# A network cable is not properly plugged in or may be broken - but works after 20 minutes?

Tags: windows-7, networking

After several years of functioning my Win7 64bit PC suddenly takes approximately 20 minutes to find out that the network cable is actually plugged in. I tried to restart PC and network many times. The same cable works immediately on other PC. I'm not aware of any changes to my system that could cause this behaviour. How to fix?

Comment: Have you tried installing a network card  into the system to verify the problem still exists with it?

Comment: "20 minutes to find out"  what information are you seeing to determine that? What is the Network Adapter item your using? Are there any other network adapters like wireless? (and what is their metric/priority) . What are your network adapter "hardware" settings set for? either in the "advanced" tab of the driver in Device Manager or via the network and sharing centers "Properties" of the adapter/connection once in proerties go to "Config" to get to the same advanced tab.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the Network interface driver issue. I would recommend you to uninstall the Network interface driver: Download recent network driver from the vendor site.

Press Windows key+r > type devmgmt.msc > select the Network interface > right click and Uninstall > now, double click and install the downloaded network interface driver and check your results.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar failures in several inexpensive network adapters.  All of them seem to be hardware failures in the adapter that just come with age. I would replace the network adapter, preferably with an internal expansion card.  Nearly any adapter for whatever bus is available should be fine.  An external (e.g. USB) adapter should be fine too, I just prefer internal.